# C# - Capture Screenshot - 60FPS

Tags: c#, windows, screenshot, capture, screen-capture

I need to capture the screen faster:
I'm using Visual Studio C# Windows Form (.Net 6.0) - 1440p Screen Resolution

Iv tried bellow and a few others and they all seem to take 30+ms for CopyFromScreen to complete:

```
        Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(frame as Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, frame.Size);            
        return frame;
```

I'm doing object detection with machine learning, the detection takes 30ms-50ms.

Making the whole loop take 80ms and this is to long.

How can I capture the screen faster?
Id like to avoid using extra hardware like a capture card.

If I use video capture code it only takes 0.2ms to grab a frame.
But this is from a video device and not desktop directly.

```
using Emgu.CV;

Mat frame = new();
var capture = new VideoCapture(0, VideoCapture.API.DShow);
capture.Read(frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's realist to try to use GDI to capture 60FPS video... Instead, you should use a tool like ffmpeg to capture video directly, including audio. You don't need extra hardware for this, just download ffmpeg and use a command line like this:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek Audio)" 
       -f gdigrab -itsoffset 00:00:0.6 -i desktop -c:v libx264rgb 
       -framerate 60 -crf 20 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

This captures using DirectShow, including the audio from the specified audio output device, and offsets the audio by a short delay to sync it up with video. The -c:v parameter specifies the video codec, -crf specifies the compression (1-50, lower is better but bigger, default is 23), -preset ultrafast specifies the bitrate.

You can call that from C# if you want, of course...

Comment: How can output just a frame to bitmap or image 
I need one frame at a time to analyze instantly.

Comment: Then you would use the code you have above, but you won't do it at 60FPS...